# how can i get all next dates with day from given date which is based on weekly, biweekly, monthly in php?

Tags: php

I want all next dates with day from specified date for sending mail within `cron` job file.
right now I m checking for whether its week by calculating like this

```
$event_from_date    =   strtotime(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($rs->from_date)));
    $today_date     =   strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));

    $event_expire_on    =   strtotime($rs->to_date);
    if($rs->time_zone   ==  "CST")
        $current_date=strtotime($cst_date);
    elseif($rs->time_zone   ==  "PST")
        $current_date=strtotime($pst_date);
    elseif($rs->time_zone   ==  "MST")
        $current_date=strtotime($est_date);
    elseif($rs->time_zone   ==  "EST")
        $current_date=strtotime($mst_date);

if($current_date <= $event_expire_on && $current_date >= $event_from_date)
{
    $diff=$today_date-$event_from_date;
    if($diff%604800 ==  0 && $rs->report_cycle=="Weekly")  
        $flag   =   1;
    else
        $flag   =   0;
}
```

can any body tell me . how can I get all next 7 days for weekly,15 days for biweekly,30 days for monthly with its day like Monday,Tuesday..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I have understood your question. The [DateTime classes](http://php.net/datetime) offer simple ways of manipulating dates and times in all manner of ways.

I think, in your position I would be looking for [DatePeriods](http://php.net/dateperiod) to represent the various erm, periods I need. A function like this may suit:-

```
/**
 * @param Int $days
 * @return DatePeriod
 */
function getNumDays($days)
{
    $today = new \DateTime('UTC');
    $oneDay = new \DateInterval('P1D');

    return new \DatePeriod($today, $oneDay, $days);
}

foreach(getNumDays(7) as $day){
    //Do what ever you want with the DateTime instance
    //We'll just var_dump() it for now.
    var_dump($day);
}
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/XTTmv).